# Pyinstaller generated EXE file does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, exe, pyinstaller

I have a complex `Python` project and I have to create a stand-alone executable (`*.exe`).

I use the `Pyinstaller`.

I have solved all dependencies (Python packages, DLLs, SDKs etc...) the `Pyinstaller` finished the `exe` creation successfully.

But when I want to run the generated `exe` file, I get a pop-up error message and that's it, nothing more.

**My project tree:**

```
>>> tree /F
C:.
│   custom_logger.py
│   file_handler.py
│   generate_pdf_from_source.py
│   gui.py
│   gui.spec
│   info_img.png
│   init_tool.bat
│   main.py
│   README.txt
│   real_time_plotter.py
│   report_generation.py
│   start_thermal_cam_tool.vbs
│   utils.py
│   visualization.py
│   __init__.py
│
└───logs
        file_handler.log
```

My project uses the files from the root folder and uses the `logs` folder to save the generated log files. Other folders (I have removed them from above tree) are not used by script, only administrative folders/contents.

**Used `Pyinstaller` command:**

```
pyinstaller.exe -Fw --clean gui.spec
```

**Some last lines of log of command:**

```
147702 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
150141 INFO: Looking for eggs
150141 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\milan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python37.dll
150141 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
150171 INFO: Warnings written to C:\Users\milan\Desktop\thermal_cam\build\gui\warn-gui.txt
150764 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\Users\milan\Desktop\thermal_cam\build\gui\xref-gui.html
151235 INFO: Appending 'datas' from .spec
151315 INFO: checking PYZ
151315 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
151327 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\milan\Desktop\thermal_cam\build\gui\PYZ-00.pyz
157984 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\Users\milan\Desktop\thermal_cam\build\gui\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
158139 INFO: checking PKG
158139 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
158139 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
225097 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
225347 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\milan\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\runw.exe
225347 INFO: checking EXE
225347 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
225347 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
225347 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\Users\milan\Desktop\thermal_cam\dist\gui.exe
225673 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Based on the above log the generation was successful (Nothing error/warning visible in other part of log).

**Content of `gui.spec` file:**

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['gui.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\milan\\Desktop\\thermal_cam'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[('C:\\Users\\milan\\Desktop\\thermal_cam\\*.py', '.'), ('C:\\Users\\milan\\Desktop\\thermal_cam\\*.png', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          [],
          name='gui',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          upx_exclude=[],
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False )
```

**Getting error:**

[image: my getting error]

**Used setup:**

- PyInstaller: 3.5
- Python: 3.7.5
- Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0

**Additional info:**

I have tried to make my `exe` file in a Python virtual environment but it did not solve my problem.

When I remove the `-w` option from my `Pyinstaller` command and run the `exe` file from CMD I also don't see anything. I get back the prompt and that's it.

**My questions:**

- Of course, How can make `exe` file work?
- Why do I get that error?
- Why don't I get more details about error in console/pop-up window?

Comment: I don't know if pyinstaller is capable of including files like this .bat and .vbs - maybe there's a problem? Also, i've had trouble using some 3rd party modules when trying to create a .exe file, whatever i tried, it didn't work. My "solution" was: I found a similar module i could use, that worked as .exe -.-

Comment: Only the `*.py` and `.png` files are needed for running (vbs, bat etc... are not needed). And I have added these type of files in my `spec` file...

Comment: Thanks, did not recognize this. Maybe breaking down the whole thing in small chunks helps to find what part causes the error - good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You know, probably the biggest problem (and the most strange thing) is I cannot get any error message or log or something about issues... 
And of course, I also had several problems with the 3rd party components and the dependencies but I have solved all of them and the `Pyinstaller` does not provide Warning or Error during the `exe` creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the issue. The `logs` folder has not been next to the `.exe` file and the script did not find it. If I create it by hand, the executable works fine. Furthermore, I have changed my logger module if the `logs` folder is not found, the script creates one. With this code change, I managed to create a totally stand-alone executable from my `Python` code.

The more elegant solution to use the `Tree`class from `PyInstaller`. Details: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/advanced-topics.html#the-tree-class

BUT, I am still confused why I did not get the `no such file or directory` error! As I mentioned I have tried it with and without `-w` option but I did not get any error...